# Path not being completely set in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, path, environment-variables

When I open a new cmd and print the path it is not match what is in the System > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables...  I have two directories from my User variables and a bunch from my System variables.  There seem to be quite a few random entries left out.  For example 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common' is the first entry in my system variables and it is not in the path, and the last entry in my user variables is not in my path and I really need it to be.  Any ideas what could be happening here?

EDIT: I have also found that Windows Powershell does in fact have all the correct path entries.  And the cmd output has a leading entry from the nodejs nvmw which is not in the path gui editor.  Maybe it is this nvmw upsetting things as it modifies the path to utilize different versions of the nodejs engine, but how is it doing this?  Also I have many applications like my Git Bash that cannot find things in the path so I think they are being affected like cmd is.

[image: User PATH variable]
[image: System Path variable]
[image: cmd path output]
[image: Powershell $Env:path output]

Comment: Please [edit] and include the two PATH values (system and user). Also include the full output of `path` in a `cmd` shell.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was indeed the rouge npm module nvmw

https://github.com/nanjingboy/nvmw/issues/5